# Building association proxies with through

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Taking this article as a starting point:

[Rails Way Blog - Association Proxies](http://www.therailsway.com/2007/3/26/association-proxies-are-your-friend)

and looking specifically at

```
def create
  @todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.build params[:todo_list]
  if @todo_list.save
    redirect_to todo_list_url(@todo_list)
  else
    render :action=>'new'
  end
end
```

This is a way of making sure you assign ownership to the user

**BUT** supposing the ToDo list was a many-many relationship associated in a has_many through i.e.

```
def User < AR:Base
  has_many :user_todos
  has_many :todo_lists, :through => :user_todos
end
```

At this point...

```
@todo_list = current_user.todo_lists.build params[:todo_list]
```

still works but only the todo_list is saved and not the join. How can I get the joy of association proxies without having lots of nested if/else should the join or Todo instance not validate when saved.

I was thinking of something along the lines of...

```
@todo_list = cu.user_todos.build.build_to_do(params[:todo_list])
```

but as I mentioned above the user_todos don't get saved.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Kevin.

Comment: You're talking about `User#todo_lists` and `User#todos` interchangeably, yet these are two different things since you've adjusted the structure. Renaming like that should break everything.

Comment: Ah yep. I'll change that. It still won't save the join though! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working...

At first I had:

```
@todo_list = @user.todo_lists.build params[:todo_list]
@todo_list.save!
```

This works when TodoList simply belongs_to User but not when it's a many-to-many relationship. When I changed the relationship I had to do...

```
@todo_list = @user.todo_lists.build params[:todo_list]
@user.save!
```

This saved the @user, the join and the @todo_list.

Obvious I suppose but then I wonder if the original example should also

```
current_user.save!
```

instead of

```
@todo_list.save!
```

I thought the idea behind **build** was that it validates and saves the associations when you save the parent so does the example at [Rails Way](http://www.therailsway.com/2007/3/26/association-proxies-are-your-friend) miss the point? or more likely am I?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something along the lines of:

```
current_user.todo_lists << TodoList.new(params[:todo_list])
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. I've never really understood the difference between build and what you've done here to be honest. Not sure if this is a good answer or not!? :) but thanks for making me look at it differently.

Comment: Thinking about it some more - I guess build allows you to assign the new ToDoList instance to a variable on a single line. without having to do:

@todo_list = ToDoList.new(params[:todo_list])
current_user.todo_lists << @todo_list